# How determine already favorited items by user in result list from get request

Tags: angular

With a GET request, I want to determine which of the results have already been favorited or liked by the current user by using the id of each object. I have a service which determines if the user has already liked an object, but with multiple items on a page, the liked/favorited status is set to the boolean of the last result. I am using an *ngFor in my front end to loop through the items so is there a way to set the boolean for favorited/not favorited for each as it loops through?

Basically I have been looping through and I can verify that the favorited service is working correctly, but each result is set to the boolean of the final item on the list instead of each retaining its own favorited ? status.

HTML:

```
 <div fxFlex *ngIf="houses" class="col-md-12">
  <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="16:5" >
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let house of houses"  class="tile">  
              <h4 {{house.address | uppercase}} </h4>
        <button mat-button 
                    (click)="addToFavorites(house._id)"><span class=" 
                     {{like ? 'fas fa-heart' : 'far fa-heart'}}"></span> 
                    </button>
            </mat-grid-tile>
     </mat-grid-list> 
  </div>
```

From my Component:

```
  this.houseService.getHouses()
       .subscribe((houses) => {
        this.houses = houses;
                  houses.forEach(function(houseStruct, i) {
                    liked = false;
                    var house = this.houses[i]._id;
                    var liked = this.houses[i].liked;

                    this.likesService.isLike(house)
                    .subscribe(resp => { console.log(resp);
                      this.like = <boolean>resp.exists;

                    if (this.like) {
                      liked = true;
                    } else {
                      liked = false;
                    }
                })
              });
```

Every time the HTML iterates over houses the like ? each house should retain its own like status, but all houses are taking the final result of like.
Thanks!

Comment: May be because you are referring to 'like' in HTML instead of 'liked'? Try changing
 {{like ? 'fas fa-heart' : 'far fa-heart'}} to  {{liked ? 'fas fa-heart' : 'far fa-heart'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `this.like`, you're setting that value for ALL the items. `this` here refers to the single component that contains the loop.

You need to set a value per item and then use that value in the loop, for example setting `house.like` and then using that in the binding.